# winsock2 client cannot send message to server

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I am trying to have my client connect to the server (both C++ & winsock2) and do authentication but always failed. The server seems okay because I can telnet to the server and manually type in the password(which is 888) and get the response from server. The telnet session looks like this:

[telnet works fine with server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkNvh.png)

I have search through internet for usage of send and recv but they just don't work here. I have also trying to append "\r" or "\n" after the password and also not working.
Here is the server code:

```
strcpy_s(sendBuff, "200 Welcome.\r\n");
send(client, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff), 0);
while (true)
{
    memset(rcvBuffer, 0,1024);
    input="";

    int n;
    while ((n = recv(client, rcvBuffer, sizeof(rcvBuffer),0))>0)   <<- server keeps waiting here
    {
        if(strchr(rcvBuffer, '\n') != 0)
            break;
        if (n>0)
            input.append(rcvBuffer, n);
    }
    if (n == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Detect client disconnection" << endl;
        break;
    }
    cout <<"Got message from client["<< input << "] sizeof(input) is" <<input.size()<< endl;

    if (ParseCmd(input.c_str(), cmd, params)){
        if (cmd == "QUIT"||cmd=="quit")
            break;
        if (cmd == "AUTH"||cmd=="auth"){
            for (struct_user u : user) {
                if (params == u.passwd){
                    this_user=u;
                    auth = true;
                    strcpy_s(sendBuff, "200 You are logged in.\r\n");
                    send(client, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff), 0);
                }
            }
            if (auth != true) {
                strcpy_s(sendBuff, "401 Bad password.\r\n");
                send(client, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff), 0);
                cout << "Bad Password" << endl;
            }
        }
        if (cmd == "gethsi"||cmd=="GETHSI"){
... some codes here
        }           // end of gethsi

    }
    else
    {
        strcpy_s(sendBuff, "400 Invalid command.\r\n");
        send(client, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff), 0);
        cout << "Invalid command" << endl;
    }
```

Here is the client code:

```
memset(rcvbuff, 0, 512);
rcvResult = recv(ConnectSocket, rcvbuff, 512, 0);               //Get welcome message
rcvbuff[rcvResult] = 0;
cout << "rcvbuf [welcome] " << rcvbuff << endl;

if (rcvbuff[0] == '2'&&rcvbuff[1] == '0'&&rcvbuff[2] == '0') {
    memset(sendbuff, 0, 512);
    strcpy_s(sendbuff, "auth 888");
    sendResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuff, strlen(sendbuff), 0);
    if (sendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    std::printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", sendResult);

    memset(rcvbuff, 0, 512);
    rcvResult = recv(ConnectSocket, rcvbuff, 512, 0);    <<-- keep waiting here
    rcvbuff[rcvResult] = 0;
    cout << "rcvbuf [authenticate] " << rcvbuff << endl;
```

The client has received the "200 Welcome" message and send out the "auth 888" message and keep waiting in "     rcvResult = recv(ConnectSocket, rcvbuff, 512, 0);" as it has not receive anything from server. Server is waiting in the recv command waiting for input.

I was also thinking appending "\r\n" after the "auth 888" but very strange thing happens. See below picture. The upper half is client and lower half is server:

[After appending "\r\n" to send string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7GXq.png)

Basically the server can only receive null string from the client as the size is 0.

I spend whole day and could not figure out why and hope somebody can help here. Thank you very much in advance.

P.S. I do not have enough reputation to post image. Hope somebody can help to post it for me. Thanks!

Nelson

Comment: When you receive data, you break if you find an \n and append to `input` only if you don't. So if you receive an `auth 888\n` you break, `input` is empty. If you receive `auth 888`, you loop forever.

Comment: Unrelated: you use `strchr` on the received data. For this to work, you have to make sure that the received data is null-terminated. In the unlikely event of receiving exactly 1024 bytes, this will not be the case.

Comment: @Karsten Koop Do you mean a "\n" afterward will clear out the send buffer so that is why I receive null string on server?

Comment: not clear the buffer, but data is only appended to `input` after the `if (strrch(.., '\n')!=0) break;` line, so when receiving an '\n', the current data is not added. You have to switch the order of statements there

Comment: @Karsten Koop: Thanks I didn't notice I make such a mistake there. It works now. Thank you.